# React JS correct file/directory structure

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm learning how to use React and I'm reading and going through the examples from [this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920049579.do).

Since I'm new to React I want to make sure I follow the correct conventions. I've gone through the examples on the book and the accompanying files in [Github](https://github.com/MoonHighway/learning-react). However, I'm stumped on one exercise as far as how am I suppose to set up the file structure.

For each exercise I've taken the sample files and separated into components and used Webpack. On this particular example I'm not sure how the file structure should be set up. What goes in the `index.js` file and how are the other components supposed to be set up?

This is the [example file](https://github.com/MoonHighway/learning-react/blob/master/chapter-07/06-managing-state-outside-react/01-state.html) for the exercise.

I created a `lib.js` file with all of the time functions. And I created an `alarmclockdisplay.js` component that will display the time. What am I suppose to put in the `index.js` file?? I tried adding the higher ordered function but I get an error when I try to compile with webpack. I got it to work correctly by just putting the `startTicking` function from `lib.js`, but this just seems different from what the previous exercises look like. The `index.js` file has always included the `render` method with JSX so I just want to make sure I'm doing it correctly.

This is how I got it to work:

```
**index.js file**

import { startTicking } from './lib'


startTicking()
```

> 

```
**lib.js file**

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AlarmClockDisplay from './alarmclockdisplay'


const oneSecond = () => 1000
const getCurrentTime = () => new Date()
const clear = () => console.clear()
const log = message => console.log(message)



      const abstractClockTime = date =>
        ({
          hours: date.getHours(),
          minutes: date.getMinutes(),
          seconds: date.getSeconds()
        })

      const civilianHours = clockTime =>
        ({
          ...clockTime,
          hours: (clockTime.hours > 12) ? clockTime.hours - 12 : clockTime.hours
        })
      const appendAMPM = clockTime =>
        ({
          ...clockTime,
          ampm: (clockTime.hours >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM"
        })        

      const display = target => time => target(time)        

      const formatClock = format =>
        time =>
          format.replace("hh", time.hours)
            .replace("mm", time.minutes)
            .replace("ss", time.seconds)
            .replace("tt", time.ampm)      

      const compose = (...fns) =>
        (arg) =>
          fns.reduce(
            (composed, f) => f(composed),
            arg
          )
      const convertToCivilianTime = clockTime =>
        compose(
          appendAMPM,
          civilianHours
        )(clockTime)
      const prependZero = key => clockTime =>
        ({
          ...clockTime,
          [key]: (clockTime[key] < 10) ? "0" + clockTime[key] : clockTime[key]
        })
      const doubleDigits = civilianTime =>
        compose(
          prependZero("hours"),
          prependZero("minutes")
        )(civilianTime)


      const render = Component => civilianTime =>
        ReactDOM.render(
          <Component {...civilianTime} />,
          document.getElementById('react-container')
        )        

export const startTicking = () =>
setInterval(
  compose(
    getCurrentTime,
    abstractClockTime,
    convertToCivilianTime,
    doubleDigits,
    render(AlarmClockDisplay)
  ),
  oneSecond()
)
```

> 

```
**alarmclockdisplay.js file**

const AlarmClockDisplay = ({hours, minutes, seconds, ampm}) =>
    <div className="clock">
        <span>{hours}</span>
        <span>:</span>
        <span>{minutes}</span>
        <span>:</span>
        <span>{seconds}</span>
        <span>{ampm}</span>
    </div>

export default AlarmClockDisplay
```

Comment: If you install the react-cli package you can then create a boilerplate app with that uses the structure that the community seems to find most effective.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The book touched on that package a little too. I'm not sure if it would help me here though. The problem is that I already have a working file. I just would like to know the correct way to break it up into separate files like it has instructed in previous exercises. Specifically the `index.js` file. It just seems way different to not include the `render` method and `JSX`. And since I'm new to React I'd like to know if the way I got it to work is correct.

Comment: It will take you less than a minute to do the whole thing if you have node installed.  You make a create-react-app, look at it in your editor, and delete it if you don't want to use it.

Comment: @stever Thanx for your help, I will def look into create-react-app. I guess the title I chose is a little misleading. I mainly interested in learning what should go inside `index.js`. All of the previous examples included a render method with `JXS`, however when I tried adding the higher order function , which includes the render method, to this example I got an error. I got it to work with the code I included but I'd like to know if this is the correct way or if I should have rewritten the higher order function in a different way so I could include it in `index.js`.

Comment: The way I've been building React apps (the CRA way) is by importing the root App.js calling ReactDOM.render() in the index.js file.

Comment: @stever Thanx. So from your experience you should always call `ReactDOM.render()` from the `index.js`? That's what I was thinking but I want to get the input from more experienced React developers.

Answer (score 0):

There are many far more experienced React developers than I, but I treat calling `ReactDOM.render()` in `index.js` as default behavior, to perform the bare necessities.  There are many situations when it is not appropriate, such as when using some navigators.  In fact you don't really NEED an index.js file.  My rule of thumb is that `ReactDOM.render()` goes at the top of the stack.

Have a look at some examples on gitHub and you'll see many different configurations.  [this tutorial is quite good](https://www.taniarascia.com/getting-started-with-react/)
The mods have asked us to stop using comments for extended conversations so I guess this is my answer.

Dan Abramov, the author of Redux has a somewhat snarky website devoted to [react file structure](http://react-file-structure.surge.sh/).

[Have a look at the official ReactDOM docs as well.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html)

It might be a good idea to experiment around a little until you come up with a more specific question.